# Expo - Continue Upload on if component unmount

Tags: react-native, expo, background-process

In my react native (Expo) application the user has the possibility to select images for a group from the gallery to upload them to the server.

When the User selects the images in the Mediapicker Screen i store the list of the uris in the Asyncstorage and navigate back to the "group screen".

Here i read the data from the asyncstorage

```
_retrieveUpload = async () => {
 try {
   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("upload_que");
   if (value !== null) {
     this.setState({ uploadQueue: JSON.parse(value) });
   }
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
};
```

in the next step i created a component which takes this.state.uploadQueue as property, iterate over the values and upload them to the server.
This is working as long as the component is mounted and the user does not leave the screen.

I read that there is no possibility for a background-task in expo, but how can i start something like a service which runs independent from the actual mounted component?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you post you Upload Component source code for more details.
Also please try in your upload code  if you have  await syntax, remove it and work with 'promise' and 'then' syntax if you need to do something  after upload.